# mongodb looping collection + save, objects returned several times

Tags: mongodb

I'm writing a pretty big migration and had this code (coffeescript):

```
db.users.find().forEach (user)->
  try
    #some code changing the user depending on the old state
    db.users.save(user)
    print "user_ok: #{user._id}"
  catch error
    print "user_error: #{user._id}, error was: #{error}"
```

Some errors occured. But they occured on already processed users:

```
 user_ok: user_1234
 #many logs
 user_error: user_1234 ...
```

***How come the loop takes already processed objects?***

I ended up doing:

```
backup = { users: [] }
db.users.find().forEach (user)->
  try
    #some code changing the user depending on the old state
    backup.users.push user
    print "user_ok: #{user._id}"
  catch error
    print "user_error: #{user._id}, error was #{error}"
#loop backup and save
```

And it works nice now, but it seems really weird. What's the point behind all that please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you modify an object, it might be moved by the database. The database needs to take additional care to remember which objects have been visited already. This feature is called [snapshotting](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/snapshot/), you can ask for a snapshotted query using

```
db.collection.find().snapshot()
```

However, even this doesn't make guarantees about objects that were inserted or deleted during the cursor iteration. A few more caveats are explained in the link to the documentation.

Another option is to perform an `$orderby` on an invariable unique index. Ideally, that index is also monotonic, so if you are using ObjectIds as primary keys then the `_id` field comes in pretty handy, like

```
db.collection.find().sort({"_id" :1});
```